# Philosophers on the process of abstraction?

Tags: abstract, abstraction

I see that there is an emphasis on studying the abstract using philosophy, but not much about abstraction. For example, I am interested in the discussion of the following two questions:

0. How would one define abstraction in broad sense?
1. When is it valid to abstract from a set of examples?

I also found this [related discussion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91205/how-understand-abstraction-when-some-cases-can-t-be-abstracted) which talks about 1., and  [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77355/goals-and-benefits-of-the-process-abstraction-for-minds) which talks about 0. but specifically for the mind.

Comment: To Master Gideon, a 7th grade student in Oregon, abstraction is simply a pounding headache. To me, a child in a man's body, abstraction is, sadly, not what I intuited it to be. Bummer!

Comment: 0. Generalization. 1. When it helps.

Comment: See [Bäck, The Concept of Abstraction](https://orb.binghamton.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1375&context=sagp) on Aristotle's theory, and [Hill, Abstraction and Idealization in Husserl and Cantor](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233588753_Abstraction_and_Idealization_in_Edmund_Husserl_and_Georg_Cantor_Prior_to_1895).